# Create virtual directory in IIS 6 and IIS 7/7.5 using C#

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

I have installer that will create virtual directory.

It works fine on IIS 6.

But if I try on IIS 7.5 it crashes.

Then i tried using Microsoft.Web.Administration class

But now it will work only on IIS 7 and IIS 7.5

Can anyone help me out so that my code works for both IIS 6 and IIS 7.5?

Comment: Can you post the code that you used?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Finally I have created 2 separate classes for managing IIS6 and IIS7.5.

And its working fine.

Comment: You were willing to take from this community but not give

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same code to create websites on both IIS6 and IIS7 (which I suspect is using the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace) then you need to install the IIS6 Management Compatibility features. You can do this by adding this as a Role Service to the Web Server role in Server Manager (under Administrative Tools).

Alternatively you can use the command line on Windows 2008 and Windows 2008R2 (run as Administrator):

**Windows 2008/2008R2 -**

`servermanagercmd -i Web-Mgt-Compat -a`

**Windows 2008R2 -**

`ServerManagerCmd.exe` is deprecated and you are advised to use the ServerManager PowerShell module:

```
import-module ServerManager
add-windowsfeature Web-Mgt-Compat -includeallsubfeature
```

Comment: Thanxs for reply..But I want the code in C# language...Also I cant enable IIS6 compatible mode on server as I dont have rights

Comment: @Sunil - unfortunately in this case you're going to have to maintain one codebase for IIS6 (System.DirectoryServices) and one for IIS7 (Microsoft.Web.Administration).